# Removing blank pages in report

Tags: jasper-reports, report, subreport

I'm currently new using *iReport* to create reports.

My main report is just one long page with many *subreports*. Every time I run my *subreports* alone with no data it says no pages, but with my main report, it shows blank pages. I want it to show only the pages with data, and those pages without data should not have blank pages.

I placed my *subreports* in report groups:

```
Group
Subreport
Subreport
Group
```

and it is repeated at around 5-6 times. I have already set all of my reports including my main report the ***When no data = No Pages***,  and I have also checked the remove line when blank in the common properties for all *subreport* elements. My main report does not have a query so I placed a simple *`SELECT 1`*.

P.S. *I can't post my code due to the fact that I'm not allowed to export and import code in the office.*

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The only "trouble" is that the *Group Header* band has its own height. You can decrease this value and check the *Group's* properties

Comment: I've actually ask for my supervisor's help, and apparently we couldn't find any solution to this, since the subreport would still reproduce a blank page even if I've set the pages without data to no pages, so we had n choice but not to remove the blank pages, and instead replace them with no data sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to go to edit query of your subreport and set the record node (Xpath generation).....it will remove the problem of subreport that is NO PAGES IN DOCUMENT...